# React. Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have child and parent components:

Parent:

```
class CustomerTable extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            customers: [],
            deletedItemId: ''
        }

      deleteItemHandler = () => {
    axios.delete(`/internal/api/Customer/${this.state.deletedItemId}`, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(resp => {
        var array = [...this.state.customers];
        array = array.filter(function (item) {
            return item.Id !== resp.data;
        });
        this.setState({ customers: array });
    }).catch(error => {

    });
}
    }
      render () {
           return (
              <ul>
                 {
                  this.state.customers.map((item, key) => {
                        return (
                            <li className="d-flex item-default" key={key}>
                                <CustomerTableRow
                                    customer={item}/>
                            </li>);
                    })
                 }
              </ul>

               <DeleteCustomerModal
                deleteItem={this.deleteItemHandler}/>
             );
     }

}
```

Child:

```
class DeleteCustomerModal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
     render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input onClick={this.props.deleteItem}/>
             </div>
           );
         }
}
```

So, child component - it's a modal window where I call an event from Parent component.

In Parent event I should to filter an array of customers and delete item and then to update the parent's state and re-render this array in a loop. But when I try this, I have an error in console: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

Where is my mistake? 
P.S. I'm new in React.

Comment: As I cannot see setState anywhere, ${this.state.deletedItemId} == "" in your API call. How are you setting your state?

Comment: A render function should not return multiple children at the root level. Wrap the return of the render function in `CustomerTable ` in a `<div>` or `<React.Fragement>`.

Comment: how do you know what to delete?

Comment: Where is this `removeChild` error coming from? Could you post the stack trace?

Comment: The error comes when I try to update state: `this.setState({ customers: array });`

Comment: I feel like some code is missing. Can you setup a sandbox?